Is there a way to append materials from Asset browser without packing the textures into the file?
I'm making my own material Asset browser library to use in different scenes. Is it possible to append those objects into a new Blender file but so that the textures aren't duplicated in this file.
I'd like it so that I could edit the material but the image textures wouldn't be packed into every file. Like what would happen if you just set up a material manually from a directory.
